# Imploding a MySQL array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble imploding a MySQL database array, below is a sample of the code I am using:

```
mysql_select_db($database_wlast, $wlast);
$query_category = "SELECT product_name FROM raw_materials WHERE category = '$_POST[category]'";
$category = mysql_query($query_category, $wlast) or die(mysql_error());
$row_category = mysql_fetch_array($category);

$result= implode(',',$row_category);

echo $result;
```

The result is the following:

```
Amber glass bottle 100ml, Amber glass bottle 100ml
```

i.e: it is spitting out the first value in the array twice and nothing else.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row_category = mysql_fetch_array($category)){
   $result[] = implode(',',$row_category);
}
echo implode("\n",$result);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_fetch_array($category, MYSQL_NUM)` or `mysql_fetch_row($category)` or `mysql_fetch_assoc($category)`

The problem is that by default `mysql_fetch_array` returns enumerated and associative arrays combined.

Answer (score 0):

That's how mysql_fetch_array() returns the result, twice: a numeric key and a string key. You possibly want `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implode all your product name from your database? if yes, than your code above is wrong.

mysql_fetch_array($category) only return 1 row of your database. If you want to implode of your all product name than code should like this:

```
$result="";
while($row_category=mysql_fetch_array($category))
   $result=$result.",".$row[0];
```

or you some thing like this. You hold all your product name on array and implode it. Like this:

```
    while($row_category=mysql_fetch_array($category))
   $result[]=$row[0];

$newResult=implode(",",$result);
```